# Using Loop Variable to Set the id Attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following code:

```
<% @electives.each do |elective| %>
  <div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I would like to set the **id** of the div to `elective.name`, but I don't know how to do it, or whether this works:

```
<% @electives.each do |elective| %>
  <div id="elective.name">
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Is it possible to do this in Rails?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `<%= ruby variable %>` block within erb file to add ruby values within your pages

```
<div id="<%= elective.name %>">
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative solution, you can use the rails [tag helper](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v7.0/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper.html#method-i-tag)

```rb
<% @electives.each do |elective| %>
  <%= tag.div id: elective.name do %>
    ... 
  <% end %> 
<% end %>
```